# Publishing a Visualization

Tags: carto, publishing

After creating a Visualization I don't see the Publish button on the top right of the page, instead I see a Share button. Where is the Publish button?

Answer (score 1):

Share and publish mean the same thing. When you hit **share** in your visualization, you are given a direct link (that is shortened), an iframe piece of code for embedding within HTML webpages, and a viz.json for including in CartoDB.js javascript code.

More info is here: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#share-your-visualization